# Exporting image data with Data URI Scheme to Excel (in my case, in PHP)

Tags: php, html, export-to-excel

For the past few hours I've been trying to get image data into an Excel sheet.

As some of you might know, Excel can import HTML pages.

Now, this all works beautifully with tables alone. Though, when I want to add some image data like so:

```
<img src="data:[mime-type];[compression-type],[data]">
```

I get a red X and the following message:

```
The image cannot be displayed. Your computer may not have enough memory...
```

Comment: Why not create a real Excel file: you're not actually using a "special header"; you're just lying to your browser telling it that HTML markup is an Excel file

Comment: Why? For one, this is much easier. I can just pass it a table, instead of explicitly assigning each table cell an Excel cell.

On your second point: it does not matter in this case. The file gets opened in Excel, that is what matters.

Comment: From what you show it would seem Excel doesn't support the `data:` URI scheme. If that's the case, I don't think anything can be done about it. It might be worth trying out with the simplest possible scenario though (A base64 encoded RGB JPEG)

Comment: Mmmhm.. yeah, I guess I should try that. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: One reason why is that more recent versions of Excel recognise that the file you're sending isn't an Excel file, but HTML... and throw a warning message when you try to open that file in Excel - it looks really professional when it happens

Comment: Ah, good call. I currently do not own the latest copy of Office so I cannot check, but if this is indeed the case (Excel throws a warning), then this obviously isn't the way to go. Thanks for that and have a good day :)